# Swing Application Barcode reader using Scanner

Tags: java, swing, barcode

I am making an java dektop application, in which i need to read some barcode from physical product and set in jtextfield. 
I found one reference but not code.

reference link is: https://youtu.be/AJS_kGRJ_Xg

So please suggest me better solution for this.

Thank's In Advance.
Jitendra Malviya
Email id: jitendramalviya39@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barcode Scanner Working logic is very simple (Barcode scanner issue Enter key event or Tab key event after reading each barcode value ),

```
You can read the barcode in jtextfieled .At the End of the barcode value, Barcode scanner will automatilly trigger the enter keyevent or Tab key . 
   1 .You Can use the key event(enter or tab) to Idenntify the barcode scanning is completed or not.
  2. Once you receive the "Enter or TAB key event" .You need to read the value from  jtextfield,Using this value you can search the product related to that barcode value.
```

Comment: can u please share exact code related to that ?? bar code scanner in swing and should auto fill in text box after scanning,

Comment: You no need to write any code explicitly to auto fill the text box after scanning . Just place your cursor in jtextfiled and scan the barcode .Definitely you will get the barcode value in jtextfiled..